# Javascript object property doesn't update each time it's accessed

Tags: javascript, oop, object, properties

oDevice has Connect() and Disconnect() functions. When connected, oTest.Capabilities returns data. When disconnected, accessing oTest.Capabilities should throw an exception. It looks like after the oTest.Capabilities property is created, it stays the same value. Accessing that property doesn't cause it to call "this.oDevice.DeviceCapabilities" again to get a new value. Is there any way to get it to update each time it's accessed?

```
var oTest = new Test();

function Test()
{   
    this.oDevice = new ActiveXObject("DeviceNMS.DeviceCLS");
    this.oDevice.Connect();

    this.Capabilities = this.oDevice.DeviceCapabilities;
}
```

Comment: @NullUserException it's a controlled environment. Not run on public PCs.

Comment: Which environment is it? Does it support getters/setters?

Comment: @Bergi Just IE9 on a private PC that runs local web pages. I think NullUserException shuddered because of security vulnerabilities of ActiveXObjects, which is why I said it's a controlled environment.

Comment: @user1172282: IE[9]? *shudders* :-)

Answer (score 1):

Javascript won't run any custom code when you access a property*

So instead, make `Capabilities` a function which will run each time it's called.

```
function Test()
{   
    this.oDevice = new ActiveXObject("DeviceNMS.DeviceCLS");
    this.oDevice.Connect();

    this.getCapabilities = function() {
      return this.oDevice.DeviceCapabilities;
    }
}

var oTest = new Test();
oTest.getCapabilities(); // note the ()
```

Now everytime you call `oTest.getCapabilities()` you evaluate `this.oDevice.DeviceCapabilities` and return the result. This means you always get an up to date value.

Or even better, put the method on the prototype!

```
function Test()
{   
    this.oDevice = new ActiveXObject("DeviceNMS.DeviceCLS");
    this.oDevice.Connect();
};

Test.prototype.getCapabilities = function() {
    return this.oDevice.DeviceCapabilities;
};

var oTest = new Test();
oTest.getCapabilities();
```

---

*There are some ways in very modern not very well supported implementations via harmony proxies... But that's a whole nother ball of yarn.

Comment: That's how I originally implemented it but I didn't want to use methods to return properties. It just seems messy to me. Can you elaborate on the "very modern not very well supported" implementations?

Comment: @AlexWayne: Proxies are not needed here, sounds he only wants a getter for the `capabilities` property.

Comment: @AlexWayne That's very interesting but unfortunately I'm using IE9 and it looks like it's not implemented yet. Unless there's another way, I may have to use methods.

Comment: @Bergi You are right, [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) might be mich better here. And it more widely supported.

Answer (score 1):

IE9? Then you can use [`Object.defineProperty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dd548687%28v=vs.94%29.aspx) as long as it is in standard mode. I would have expected `oDevice.DeviceCapabilities` to be a dynamic-updating object, too, but if it is static you can use

```
function Test() {   
    this.oDevice = new ActiveXObject("DeviceNMS.DeviceCLS");
    this.oDevice.Connect();

    Object.defineProperty(this, "capabilities", {
        get: function() {
            return this.oDevice.DeviceCapabilities;
        }
    });
}
```

to recreate it on every access of the `capabilities` property. Therefore, cache it in a variable if you plan to use it a couple of times in series (e.g. a iteration/enumeration) so that you do not call the getter function each time. Also notice that `myTest.capabilities !== myTest.capabilities` as `DeviceCapabilities` returns different objects.